# Unable to handle the Login page on naukri.com

Tags: selenium

I am trying to do the login and its not working giving error on accessing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsiXG.png) the `username` and `password` fields
enter image description here

```
    driver.get("https://www.naukri.com/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    Set<String> WH = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator <String> it = WH.iterator();
    String parentwindow =it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
    System.out.println("Switching to window - > " + parentwindow);
    String PWTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(PWTitle);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='login_Layer']")).click();;
    System.out.println("clicked and navigated to Login Frame");
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    
    WebElement block = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//span[@id='block']"))));
    block.click();
    System.out.println("clickied on Block on alert");
    
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='login-layer']")).click();
    //System.out.println("clicked on Login Fram");
    //driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
    //System.out.println("swithced to the parent window");
    
    WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your active Email ID / Username']"))));
    WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your password']"))));
    username.sendKeys("naukriuser@gmail.com");
    password.sendKeys("123456");
```

**Error log**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed0b1c69bb4e51ea0252171854915-refs/branch-heads/4606@{#1204}) on port 30575
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 17, 2021 2:08:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Switching to window - > CDwindow-E818DF558C0CF7F492AF75AB428E6D65
Jobs - Recruitment - Job Search - Employment -Job Vacancies - Naukri.com
clicked and navigated to Login Frame
clickied on Block on alert
clicked on Login Fram
swithced to the parent window
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@plcaeholder='Enter your password'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at Company3.naukridailyupdate.main(naukridailyupdate.java:42)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your password']"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'BOBBYREDE', ip: '192.168.43.21', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 94.0.4606.81, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Hai\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64003}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 7c7133d061300e1c0c20ada760d7ce62
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your password']}
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`xPath` is not valid one. There is a typo in your `xPath`. Please use below,

```
//input[@placeholder='Enter your password']
```

Always check the `xPath` in chrome console.

Open web page -> Inspect element/Press `F12` -> Go to elements tab -> `Ctrl + F` -> Place your `xPath`

If it is a valid and unique one you should see 1/1 result and element will be highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The locators you are using it here :

```
 WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your active Email ID / Username']"))));
 WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//input[@plcaeholder='Enter your password']"))));
```

looks brittles since they are totally dependent on placeholder text.

Please use below locator :

for username :

```
//label[contains(text(),'Username')]//following-sibling::input
```

for password :

```
//label[contains(text(),'Password')]//following-sibling::input
```

Your code should look like this :

```
WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Username')]//following-sibling::input"))));
WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Password')]//following-sibling::input"))));
username.sendKeys("naukriuser@gmail.com");
password.sendKeys("123456");
```